# Errors on rebooting

Tags: boot, 20.04, syslog

## Info

I have just built a system with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I suspect there are issues with my system since it is quite slow and it often freezes.

## Issue

Checking on the log file there are few errors when booting.

### Content of `/var/log/syslog` filtered by Errors

```
kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
kernel: [    0.266759] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
kernel: [    0.367310] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: TCP_NODELAY failed: Operation not supported
systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
kernel: [    3.317626] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
kernel: [    3.333975] v4l2loopback: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
thermald[1049]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml"
thermald[1049]: [WARN]error: could not parse file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
thermald[1049]: [ERR]THD engine start failed
udisksd[1050]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
udisksd[1050]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin
colord[1096]: failed to get session [pid 1014]: No data available
colord[1096]: failed to get session [pid 1014]: No data available
NetworkManager[1017]: <warn>  [1606682194.6465] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gnome-session[1276]: gnome-session-binary[1276]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gnome-session-binary[1276]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
systemd[1381]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
systemd[1381]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor: No such file or directory
systemd[1256]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1256]: Failed to start Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to query device string: The last function succeeded without error.
gnome-shell[1333]: g_str_has_prefix: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: message repeated 2 times: [ g_str_has_prefix: assertion 'str != NULL' failed]
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to get string: No error has been recorded.
gnome-shell[1333]: g_strjoinv: assertion 'str_array != NULL' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Missing OpenGL ES extensions: (null)
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gsd-sharing[1511]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gsd-sharing[1511]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gnome-shell[1333]: _clutter_stage_queue_event: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_STAGE (stage)' failed
gsd-media-keys[1535]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
gsd-media-keys[1535]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
gsd-media-keys[1535]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
gsd-media-keys[1535]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1661]: > Internal error:   Could not resolve keysym Invalid
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1661]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
gnome-shell[1333]: Warning: Failed to start gsd-xsettings
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1274]: dbus-daemon[1274]: [session uid=125 pid=1274] A     ctivated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gsd-sharing[1511]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Sp     awn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
gsd-sharing[1511]: message repeated 3 times: [ Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:o     rg.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
tracker-miner-fs[1264]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.g     tk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
tracker-extract[1263]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gt     k.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
systemd[1897]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed to execute command: No such f     ile or directory
systemd[1897]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/li     bexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor: No such file or directory
systemd[1820]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1820]: Failed to start Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1902]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (     ??) unknown.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1902]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operat     ion not permitted)
systemd[1820]: gnome-session-x11@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-ses     sion-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-failed     .target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session@gnome-initial-setup.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=     gnome-session-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session@gnome-login.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-se     ssion-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session-x11.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-fa     iled.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session     -failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session     -shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session@gnome-login.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-se     ssion-failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session-x11.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-fa     iled.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session@ubuntu.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session     -failed.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
systemd[1820]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session     -shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
gnome-session-c[2009]: Error creating FIFO: File exists
goa-daemon[1872]: /org/gnome/OnlineAccounts/Accounts/account_1606232264_0: Setting Atten     tionNeeded to TRUE because EnsureCredentials() failed with: access denied (goa-error-quark, 4)
pulseaudio[1826]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did no     t receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security      policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
tracker-miner-fs[1828]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.g     tk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
tracker-extract[1827]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gt     k.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
gnome-shell[2030]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vf     s.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
gnome-shell[2030]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error     .NotFound: No entry for geolocation
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 68 failed: Perm     ission denied
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 68 failed: Perm     ission denied
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 71 failed: Perm     ission denied
gsd-media-keys[2178]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-repeat
gsd-media-keys[2178]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:hibernate
gsd-media-keys[2178]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:playback-random
gsd-media-keys[2178]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settings:rfkill
colord[1096]: failed to get session [pid 2169]: No data available
colord[1096]: failed to get session [pid 2169]: No data available
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 68 failed: Perm     ission denied
gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to set CRTC gamma: drmModeCrtcSetGamma on CRTC 71 failed: Perm     ission denied
gnome-session[1276]: gnome-session-binary[1276]: CRITICAL: gsm_client_peek_id: assertion      'GSM_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed
gnome-session[1276]: gnome-session-binary[1276]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_find: asser     tion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
gnome-session[1276]: gnome-session-binary[1276]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale      is dead. Sorry....
gnome-session-binary[1276]: CRITICAL: gsm_client_peek_id: assertion 'GSM_IS_CLIENT (clie     nt)' failed
gnome-session-binary[1276]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash     _table->version' failed
gnome-session-binary[1276]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
gnome-session-binary[1276]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
gsd-color[2169]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/f     reedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Dell_Inc__DELL_U2717D_J0XYN655A7MS_gdm_125
gsd-color[2169]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/f     reedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Samsung_Electric_Company_T27C370_gdm_125
fwupd[2462]: 20:37:36:0724 FuPluginUefi         Error opening directory “/sys/firmware/e     fi/esrt/entries”: No such file or directory
tracker-miner-f[1264]: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
tracker-miner-f[1264]: message repeated 2 times: [ Error while sending AddMatch() messag     e: The connection is closed]
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Failed to activate service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor': timed out      (service_start_timeout=120000ms) (g-dbus-error-quark, 20)
systemd[3115]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed to execute command: No such f     ile or directory
systemd[3115]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/li     bexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor: No such file or directory
systemd[1820]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1820]: Failed to start Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
org.freedesktop.FileManager1[2143]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByNa     me for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor.desktop[3117]: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServic     eByName for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

The log file seems to suggest multiple different errors.

- The first one (`kernel: [    0.266759] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed`) is the most serious one. Try [this fix](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=323152) (Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, so it might work).
- The second one (`v4l2loopback: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`) is related to [Secure Boot signature verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin). This might have disabled loading kernel modules that contain the necessary graphics drivers, thus causing `gnome-session` (the login/session manager) and `gdm3` (the display manager) to fail. The clue is the error message `gnome-shell[1333]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Missing OpenGL ES extensions: (null)`
- Next, the missing library `libbd_mdraid.so.2`, a RAID library component, which can be fixed with `sudo apt install libblockdev-mdraid2`
- Finally, NetworkManager failed to manage the network interfaces, as seen from the warning message `NetworkManager[1017]: <warn>  [1606682194.6465] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate`. This can be caused by the VPN software (`systemd[1]: nordvpnd.socket: TCP_NODELAY failed: Operation not supported`)